# VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception in Anaconda?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, video-capture

I am trying to use the function cv2.VideoCapture in Anaconda. The code takes the desired video path as a main argument. However, when I try running the code, I get this error:

[ERROR:0@0.052] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (166) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:293: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_filename.empty() in function 'cv::CvCapture_Images::open'

I am in a virtual environment using Python 3.7 and opencv-contrib-python 4.6.0.66. Does anyone know how to resolve this error? Thanks!

Comment: Check the filepath

Comment: you can check the file path like so: `assert os.path.isfile(your_file_path)` -- you need to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the path to the opencv folder in your environment variables. Right click "This PC" -> Properties -> (In the right column) Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables. In System variables, find Path. Edit it and add the path to your opencv folder.

Or use sys.path.append(*path to your folder*) before you import.

Also, this post may help. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086395/cant-import-opencv-in-python-3#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20installed%20Anaconda%2C%20go%20to%20Anaconda,install%20the%20latest%20version%20of%20opencv%20for%20you.)